# Bulk create fails with 1 milion rows

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

For learning purposes I've created csv files with 10 000 rows and 2nd file with 1 million rows,  4 columns each. The idea is to add the data to the table most efficient. ( I am using SQL Database)

First approach - `@transaction.atomic`

```
@transaction.atomic
def insert(request):
    data_reader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for row in data_reader:
        nela = Nela()  # my model name
        nela.name = row[0]
        nela.last = row[1]
        nela.almost = row[2]
        nela.number = row[3]

        nela.save()


insert(request)
```

1) For 10 000 rows it takes 2.1006858348846436 to insert data

2) For 1 million rows it was something around ~220.xx secs

My 2nd approach is usage of `bulk_create()`

```
def insert(request):

data_reader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
header = next(data_reader)
Nela.objects.bulk_create([Nela(name=row[0], last=row[1], almost=row[2], number=row[3]) for row in data_reader])

insert(request)
```

1) for 10 000 rows it takes 0.4592757225036621  which is cool and over 4 times faster then with `@transaction.atomic`

2) However, for 1 million rows it fails and it outruns the limit of the SQL base.

Does anyone have any idea why such bug appears ?

I've been reading django docs [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) but besides annotation about `batch_size` for SQL lite I can't find anything useful.

Comment: The list comprehension `[Nela(...) for row in data_reader]` is going to load all million rows into the list before passing it to bulk create. It might be more efficient to call `bulk_create` with batches of (say) 100/1000/10000 objects. You can experiment to see which number gives the best performance.

Comment: I'm still wondering what your question is. Why the DB has limitations?

Comment: The [bulk_create doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) suggests using `islice` to do your own batching so that you don't hold all million rows in memory at once.

Comment: @KlausD. I doubt that it is limitation of my db by any kind. Since the query with `transaction.atomic` works, it has to be duo other aspects of my code, i.e. list comprehension

Comment: @tdelaney after some thoughts you may be right - keeping 1 million rows in memory may be the case, I thought that `islice` is duo the way to avoid SQLlite limitation but I've gotta check this out more thoroughly

Comment: Even if you don't create a list, django does so that it can preprocess and reorder inserts to its liking. So, do your own batching. Just use the standard `slice` function.

Comment: @tdelaney if I could mark comment as the answer for my question - I would do so. adding `batch_size` to `bulk_create` and with value of 10 000 did the job. Now it's the time to slice it to different values and find out what is most efficient.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for Your comment also, it led me to the solutions :)

Comment: I posted an answer which is how django says to do it.  I'm still a bit puzzled, shouldn't the django `batch_size` parameter do this for you?

Comment: @tdelaney indeed, simple `batch_size = 10 000` and passing this as parameter to `Nela.objects.bulk_create(batch, batch_size)` works exactly the same, without `islice` with the same efficient but still, appreciate your answer !

Comment: If you really need the fastest way to do this, skip django and go native. here is the mysql [LOAD DATA INFILE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) which is a bit of a heavy read! And the [mysqlimport tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html). Your db may have different tools but likely similar.

Comment: @tdelaney got my first job this week, my employer asked me to learn a bit about large files, efficient queries and data aggregation in terms of Django ORM - thought that what I did is something to accomplish that :) but i am gonna check that for sure, thanks !

Comment: We could chat about whether "ORM" and "efficient" belong in the same sentence... but don't tell your boss that! Congrats on the job and good luck!

Comment: @tdelaney that's something I've been thinking of but, from what i understood, they use ORM and ElasticSearch  to handle data but well, gonna see in two weeks :D Thanks again and have good day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the million object list you create and feed to `bulk_create`. Even if you just pass in an iterator, Django would turn it into a list so that it can optimize the insert before proceeding. The solution is to do your own batching outside of Django with `islice`.

```
from itertools import islice

data_reader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
header = next(data_reader)
batch_size = 10000
while True:
    batch = [Nela(name=row[0], last=row[1], almost=row[2], number=row[3])
        for row in islice(data_reader, batch_size)]
    if not batch:
        break
    Nela.objects.bulk_create(batch, batch_size)
```

Comment: i think `batch_size = 1000` will be faster than `batch_size = 10000`

Comment: @suhailvs - Its hard to guess the right size as it depends on the execution environment. Its possible that 100 is better than 1000. You'd have to run performance tests to find out.